# Large RAM sticks on older motherboard

Tags: memory, motherboard, compatibility

I have a [P55A-UD3 motherboard](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3242#ov) (rev 1.0 presumably), which supports up to 16GB of RAM. The specs doesn't say that each memory slot has a limit of 4GB, and people seem to have [installed 8GB RAM sticks on it](http://forums.overclockers.com.au/showpost.php?p=15541919&postcount=10)

My [Intel i3 530 processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/46472/Intel-Core-i3-530-Processor-4M-Cache-2_93-GHz) also supports 16GB of RAM.

However, I just got [2x8GB RAM sticks](http://www.gskill.com/en/product/f3-2400c11d-16gxm) and tried them on. The BIOS correctly identifies 16GB of RAM. The result was however, that `memtest` freezes on the very first pass as soon as it tries to test memory beyond 4GB. (FYI, I have 4x2GB RAM sticks currently and having 8GB of RAM is ok). The initial 4GB themselves seem to be accessible perfectly (I booted in Ubuntu and it was working until (I guess) it started using memory above 4GB).

What I tried:

- Update the bios to the latest firmware (from 2010 nevertheless)
- Increase voltage of RAM to 1.64
- Change timing to 11-13-13-31 as mentioned in the specs

The frequency of the RAM is 1333Hz. With any of these changes, `memtest` still freezes when trying to access addresses above 4GB.

I also tried to install the RAM sticks one at a time, but oddly enough, when I try only one (on channel 1), the POST freezes right after indicating that I have 8GB installed.

---

My question is, how else can I attack this problem? I know that the RAM sticks that I bought are tested at 2400Hz speed, and my motherboard supports a maximum of 2200Hz, but shouldn't faster RAMs work with slower clocks as well? Is my motherboard simply too old for these RAM sticks, or is there something else I can do make things work?

Comment: Is your CPU 64-bit capable?  If it's not you won't be able to get at more than 4 GB of RAM

Comment: Also make sure your memtest is 64-bit capable

Comment: @daniel, yes my CPU is x86_64. I can test my 8GB current RAM (4x2GB) with the same memtest, but I'll check it again. It got installed with a 64-bit Linux, so I immagine perhaps it's also 64-bit. By the way, with PAE you can get more than 4GB of RAM on x86 as well if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Upload a screenshot of the memtest when it freezes.